# How to store Microsoft's Dynamic Linq's OrderBy in a variable?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

Here is [Generic Repository](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com)'s way of storing an OrderBy:

```
private Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> _orderBy;
```

Here's Microsoft's OrderBy that takes a string of field names (from [Microsoft's Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)):

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, 
    string ordering, params object[] values);
```

Here's our Extension Method that translates our array of fields to a comma separated OrderBy/ThenBy:

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    ICollection<string> orderBy)
{    
    return source.OrderBy( String.Join(",", orderBy) );
}
```

All that works well but requires appending the OrderBy to the original Entity.  **How would we save the OrderBy in a variable to append to that Entity later?**

```
//Something like 
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> _orderBy = ??
```

For reference, here's Microsoft's System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicQueryable.OrderBy source ([Scott G's writeup link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)):

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source, string ordering, params object[] values) 
{
    return (IQueryable<T>)OrderBy((IQueryable)source, ordering, values);
}

public static IQueryable OrderBy(
    this IQueryable source, string ordering, params object[] values) 
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (ordering == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering");
    ParameterExpression[] parameters = new ParameterExpression[] 
    {
        Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType, "") 
    };
    ExpressionParser parser = new ExpressionParser(parameters, ordering, values);
    IEnumerable<DynamicOrdering> orderings = parser.ParseOrdering();
    Expression queryExpr = source.Expression;
    string methodAsc = "OrderBy";
    string methodDesc = "OrderByDescending";
    foreach (DynamicOrdering o in orderings) 
    {
        queryExpr = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), 
            o.Ascending ? methodAsc : methodDesc,
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, o.Selector.Type },
            queryExpr,
            Expression.Quote(Expression.Lambda(o.Selector, parameters)));
        methodAsc = "ThenBy";
        methodDesc = "ThenByDescending";
    }
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(queryExpr);
}
```

Comment: I don't comprehend... You can save the `ICollection<string>` and append it *later* (before executing the query) using the OrderBy :). In the end *later* you will need to invoke a method to append the order.

Comment: It's saving the orderBy in essentially a Query Object to be executed later, but the query object stores the orderby in a `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> _orderBy = t => t.OrderBy( String.Join(",", orderBy));
```

Comment: Definitely what I'm looking for.  The error I get is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' to 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<T>'.`

Comment: @Dr.Zim that probably means that the dynamic linq version of OrderBy doesnt return an IOrderedQueryable like the standard linq OrderBy function does. Are you able to change Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> to Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>>

Comment: I added MS's Dynamic OrderBy source for reference. For the repository, I'd rather store the OrderBy function and overload the Dynamic Linq OrderBy to return Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> if that's possible.

Comment: @Dr.Zim You can try. it should be possible and the type OrderBy returns should be an error. It should be `IOrderedQueryable<>`

Comment: @RyanDansie Changing MS's Dynamic Linq library to `IOrderedQueryable OrderBy` did the trick.